# Adding an interface to a partial class

Tags: c#, interface

I have a class that is generated by a third party tool:

```
public partial class CloudDataContext : DbContext 
{
    // ...SNIPPED... 
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } 

}
```

I create a partial class and then assign an interface so that I can inject this class later:

```
public partial class CloudDataContext : IDataContext
{

}
```

The `IDataContext` has the single property `Users`.

This won't compile, the compiler complains that the interface isn't implemented.

If I move the interface to the generated class, it works fine. I can't do that though as it's generated code.

How can I apply an interface to a partial class to expose the class as defined above?

Comment: Does DBContext not implement IDataContext?

Comment: Can you show the definition of `IDataContext` and the implementation of `CloudDataContext`? I just ran [this example](http://dotnetfiddle.net/ExiSIp) and it works just fine.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a pretty far limb here: are the `using` directives at the top of the two class files different? Is it possible that in the one code file, `IDataContext` resolves to _one_ interface, and in the other code file `IDataContext` resolves to a _second different_ interface?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The problem must be somewhere else, because you can implement interface in the other part of `partial` class than it's *set on*. I just tried following and it compiles just fine:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int Bar { get; set; }
}

public partial class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

public partial class Foo : IFoo
{

}
```

The properties probably use different types in `interface` and `class`.

Comment: Turns out it was a typo in the name space of one of the partials. Once matched, it worked.

Comment: In my case it was because the new partial class file I generated had a different class name. Remember to change the class name to match the one in the other file...

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick checklist. Do the classes have identical:

- Names?
- Namespaces?
- Access modifiers?

Example:

- You decide to split an existing class into two files.
- The original file's namespace doesn't match its folder path.
- Consequently, the new class file you create has a mismatching namespace.
- Build fails.

Answer (score 1):

IN my Case problem was that interface Method that was implemented in other part of the partial class was not compiling and C# was giving error of not implemented  Method

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the interface method signature didn't mention a value (uint direction) that the actual method expected. This showed up as the interface having errors in one of the partial classes. Make sure that the interface for a method is actually the same as the method signature itself. D'oh.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all files of the partial class have "C# compiler" Build Action in VS.